# SpringMVC - Method can return a Redirect (String) or a ModelAndView

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

My method makes a decision; in one case it redirects to a URL. In another case, it has to do a ModelAndView JSP refresh.

What should be the signature of this method?

Right now,

```
public String removeForm(final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
   if (condition1) {
      return "redirect:/myaction";
   }
   else {
      // Need to do a View, or a ModelAndView?
   }

}
```

Conversely, my method could be a ModelAndView-based method, but I'd need to return a Redirect string in one case. How to combine them?

Answer (score 7):

the most easy way is to just use `Object` for return type.

```
public Object removeForm(final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
   if (condition1) {
      return "redirect:/myaction";
   } else {
     return new ModelAndView("jspName", modelMap);
   }    
}
```

but the more elegant is to use `ModelAndView` and use the `RedirectView` in redirect case

```
public ModelAndView removeForm(final HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
{
   if (condition1) {
      return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/myaction"));
   } else {
       return new ModelAndView("jspName", modelMap);
   )
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how returning this string actually redirects the url in browser.

Comment: @Saurabh Tiwari: the prefix "redirect:" is a special keyword used by spring, see reference https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.19.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-redirecting and https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-redirecting-redirect-prefix (the 4.3 reference is a bit better to understand)

Answer (score 4):

If you need to return always a **String** ,you can use the Model class in your method and return the view name as String, it works like you return a ModelAndView:

```
 public String removeForm(final HttpServletRequest request, Model model)throws Exception
 {
     if (condition1) {
        return "redirect:/myaction";
     }else {
        model.addAtribute("objectName",object);
        return "viewName";
    }
 }
```